# How can I write xlsx to file in browser with ExcelJS?

Tags: javascript, xlsx, exceljs

I am trying to create an xlsx file in the browser and find https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs very powerful. However, I can't find a way how to save my xlsx object to a file. Probably I need to use Buffer, but how to generate a file from it?

```
const buffer = await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer();
```

This library can generate files in the browser https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/ but it is not good at building complex fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use FileSaver.js (https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

```
var FileSaver = require('file-saver');
const buffer = await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer();
FileSaver.saveAs(new Blob([buffer]), “result.xlsx”);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it without FileSaver.js.

Creating a buffer for ExcelJS:

```
let buffer = await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer();
```

Creating a buffer for SheetJS:

```
let buffer = XLSX.write(workBook, { bookType: 'xlsx', compression: true, type: 'buffer' });
```

Saving to a file for both libraries:

```
        let blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" });
        let link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = "fName.xlsx";
        link.click();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
```

Comment: The above solution results in a corrupted file. Same ExcelJS worked on node.js with `workbook.xlsx.writeFile('filename.xlsx');` without a problem.